# Cypress-cucumber error: "Your configFile threw an error from: cypress.config.js We stopped running your tests because your config file crashed"

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor, cypress-configuration

When I try to run Cucumber tests with Cypress, I get error saying:

> Your `configFile` threw an error from: `cypress.config.js`
>
> We stopped running your tests because your config file crashed.

Tried upgrading and downgrading Node.
Also tried with different `cypress-cucumber-preprocessor` but that didn't help.

My `index.js` file is:

```js
const createEsbuildPlugin =
    require('@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/esbuild').createEsbuildPlugin

const createBundler = require('@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor')
const nodePolyfills =
    require('@esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill').NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin

const addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin =
    require('@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin

module.exports = async (on, config) => {
    await addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config) // to allow json to be produced
    // To use esBuild for the bundler when preprocessing
    on(
        'file:preprocessor',
        createBundler({
            plugins: [nodePolyfills(), createEsbuildPlugin(config)],
        })
    )
    return config
}
```

And `config.js` file snippet:

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')
const selectTestsWithGrep = require('cypress-select-tests/grep')
const allureWriter = require("@shelex/cypress-allure-plugin/writer");


module.exports = defineConfig({
  env: {
    baseurl: 'https://google.com',
    username: 'admin',
    password: 'admin',
  },
  video: false,
  screenshotsFolder: 'screenshots',
  chromeWebSecurity: false,
  defaultCommandTimeout: 45000,
  pageLoadTimeout: 90000,
  screenshotOnRunFailure: true,
  viewportWidth: 1400,
  viewportHeight: 900,
  e2e: {
    specPattern: ["**/*.feature", "cypress/e2e/**/*.cy.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
    supportFile: false,
    // excludeSpecPattern: "*.js",
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      //require('cypress-mochawesome-reporter/plugin')(on);
      on('file:preprocessor', selectTestsWithGrep(config));
      allureWriter(on, config);
      return config;
    }
  }
})
```

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: did you able to reosolve the issue ?  Like to check since I am also facing the same problem

Comment: I got the same issue but in Docker.